# pandas groupby does not preserve order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

seq = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
event_no = [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
points_no = [1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 1, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({"seq" : seq, "event_no": event_no, "points_no": points_no})

seq event_no    points_no
    0   1   5   1.0
    1   1   5   1.0
    2   1   5   1.0
    3   1   6   NaN
    4   1   6   NaN
    5   1   6   NaN
    6   1   4   1.0
    7   1   4   1.0
    8   1   4   1.0
    9   2   3   1.0
    10  2   3   1.0
    11  2   3   1.0
    12  2   1   NaN
    13  2   1   NaN
    14  2   1   NaN
    15  2   2   1.0
    16  2   2   1.0
    17  2   2   1.0
```

I group it by `seq` then `event_no` and then sum over `points_no`...

```
df2 = df.groupby(['seq', 'event_no']).points_no.sum().reset_index()
```

The output below doesn't preserve the original index order of data in column `event_no`, instead they're sorted in ascending order:

```
seq event_no    points_no
0   1   4   3.0
1   1   5   3.0
2   1   6   0.0
3   2   1   0.0
4   2   2   3.0
5   2   3   3.0
```

What I actually want is this output:

```
seq event_no    points_no
0   1   5   3.0
1   1   6   0.0
2   1   4   3.0
3   2   3   3.0
4   2   1   0.0
5   2   2   3.0
```

Is there a way to get the result as stated while preserving index order?

Comment: You can use `sort=False` in your `groupby`

Comment: how is that, could you please show an example

Comment: `df.groupby(['seq', 'event_no'], sort=False).points_no.sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 7):

Use the parameter `sort=False`:

```py
df.groupby(['seq', 'event_no'], sort=False).points_no.sum().reset_index()
```